# Right way to save redux store in to cookie

Tags: reactjs, cookies, redux, react-redux

I want to save current state of Redux store. There are two options: Local Storage or Cookies. I want to save it in to cookies.
First, I save curret state to cookie like that:

```
this.props.cookies.set('cp', store.getState());
```

Then to load saved state in reducer I am using this initial state.

```
 let initialState = {}
if (cookies.get('cp')) {
    initialState = cookies.get('cp');
} else {
    initialState = {
        user: {
            loggedIn: false,
               },

    }
}
```

Is this a good or bad way to save state?

Comment: What made you choose cookies over local storage? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies This should help you decide if you've taken the right approach

Comment: @ChristopherMoore thank you for your answer. I choosed cookie because I need IE support. But now I figured out that Local Storage have IE 11 support. Maybe Local storage is  really right way...